GAM - Mostrar objeto al cual no se tiene permisos en Not Authorized Object for Web
En una KB con GX18 U6 y con las propiedades:

Enable Integrated Security = True
Integrated Security Level  = Authorization

Si un usuario no tiene permisos a un panel, se redirige automáticamente al panel que esté configurado en la propiedad "Not Authorized Object for Web", en este caso GAMExampleNotAuthorized que es el que viene por defecto:

¿Es posible recuperar de alguna forma el objeto desde el cual se llamó a este panel para mostrarle al usuario cuál es la pantalla o el permiso al cual no tiene acceso, para que en este mismo panel pueda visualizar algo así como " - Usted no posee permisos a la pantalla "NombrePantalla""?
Ya que según la documentación toda esta lógica la maneja internamente GAM.

El metodo GAMRepository.GetLastErrorsURL() te va a devolver la url que corresponde con el acceso que el usuario no pudo hacer.

Con ese método puedo obtener el nombre de la pantalla, pero ¿hay alguna forma de obtener el permiso definido para la pantalla en la propiedad "Permission Prefix"? ya que el nombre del permiso puede ser diferente del nombre de la pantalla y me gustaría que el usuario pueda saber qué permiso es el que no tiene.
